# Как переместить блоки в flexbox row?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, flexbox

Есть блок с *flexbox*, внутри есть блоки *items*.

Я хочу сделать сетку для расположения блоков. Когда все блоки одинаковой ширины, то проблемы нет. Но у меня блоки 2 видов, поэтому иногда двойной блок переносится и остается пустое место. Как его заполнить подходящим следующим элементов в линии или передвинуть двойной, чтобы не было пустых мест? Блоки выводятся в цикле PHP, поэтому использовать ордер не могу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Фрагмент кода**:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

[class*=col-1x],
[class*=col-2x] {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.col-1x,
.col-2x {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.div-1x {
  width: 270px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div-2x {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff8800;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .col-1x {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%
  }
  .col-2x {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%
  }
  .div-2x {
    width: 570px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1199px) {
  .col-1x {
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%
  }
  .col-2x {
    flex: 0 0 66.666666%;
    max-width: 66.666666%
  }
  .div-2x {
    width: 590px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .col-1x {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%
  }
  .col-2x {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .div-2x {
    width: 630px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .col-1x {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .col-2x {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .div-1x {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .div-2x {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1x">
      <div class="div-1x">1x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1x">
      <div class="div-1x">1x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2x">
      <div class="div-2x">2x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1x">
      <div class="div-1x">1x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1x">
      <div class="div-1x">1x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2x">
      <div class="div-2x">2x</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0mepcd74/1/

Comment: Один из вариантов - свойство [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Comment: Да, свойство есть такое. У меня блоки выводятся в цикле, поэтому не могу его использовать. Может быть есть вариант через js обратиться, прочитать пустое место в строке и переместить блоки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта задача волновала и волнует многих - остановился на Masonry.

> Masonry - это библиотека макетов JavaScript. Он работает, располагая элементы в оптимальном положении в зависимости от доступного вертикального пространства, вроде каменщика, подгоняющего камни к стене.

Результат можете посмотреть здесь http://coderhs.com/informers/ - поизменяйте размер окна, чтоб увидеть подстраивание - три варианта разноразмерных блоков - а может быть столько, сколько пожелается.

Сайт библиотеки: https://masonry.desandro.com/

*UPD

Еще вариант от того же автора:

Packery https://packery.metafizzy.co/

> Packery - это библиотека JavaScript и плагин jQuery, который **создает макеты без зазоров** и с возможностью перетаскивания. Он использует алгоритм упаковки для заполнения пустых пробелов. Элементы упаковки могут быть оптимально/грамотно упорядочены или оставлены в естественном расположении. Элементы могут быть зафиксированы на месте, помещены в определенное место или перетащены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Масонри по вертикали делает. Рассматривал его, но мне надо именно по горизонтали.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней - он убирает вообще свободное место - и интеграция очень проста, даже на существующие моменты. У меня три разномерных блока - и по вертикали, и по горизонтали. В общем, лучшего решения пока не видел. А если нужна выборочная сортировка - то в автомате такого совершенно не встречал - конечно, можно что-то расчитать после построения DOM и сортировать - но, это кто решит заморочиться - не видел такого, пока что.

Comment: Вот и думал на jquery после построения DOM обратиться и отсортировать. Но вот как обратиться к пустой ячейке. Тогда мог бы поиском по дереву найти элемент подходящий и его переместить. Есть возможности JS к обращению к пустому элементу в строке, не знаешь?

Comment: Нужно конкретный пример смотреть -так гадания слишком общие. И потом - а может, стоит попробовать сразу разделять получаемое по размеру, и сортировать одинаковое к одинаковому - тогда мест пустых и не будет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012428/how-to-detect-css-flex-wrap-event Покурю эту тему, может как вариант что-то найду в решении

Comment: Там другое, но лишним знания не будут - я просто к тому, что тема не нова, а решений не встречалось - мне, по крайней мере. Правда, не слишком-то и искалось.

Comment: @Александр Пахомов - посмотрите апдейт в ответе - довольно интересно.

Comment: Оогонь!) Это огонь!!! Спасибо тебе, добрый человек. Задачу решил свою) https://jsfiddle.net/xobr71Le/

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!

Comment: Добрый человек, не поможешь еще?)) Использую плагин, который посоветовал посмотреть. Видимо я где-то в css напутал. При добавлении элементов они появляются под блоками. https://jsfiddle.net/dbxetmy5/

Comment: Может, попробовать заменить юappend на .prepend()  .prependTo()? Попробовать вариации.

Comment: Не работает тоже. Блоки добавляются под слой. Если сделать .packery('reloadItems').packery(); тогда все получается нормально. Но я хочу уйти от инициализации по-новой.

Answer (score 2):

По итогу я заставил работать все так, как хотел. От Flexbox'а необходимо избавиться для достижения желаемого. За идею спасибо отдельное @Coder

**Что надо сделать:**

1. Забыть про флексбокс
2. Обратить внимание на [библиотеку Packery](https://packery.metafizzy.co/)
3. Сделать разметку и, если необходимо, подгружать блоки дальше
4. Если подгружаете Ajax'сом, то обработать ответ `$.parseHTML(data);`. Как глупец из-за этого я убил столько времени, т.к. боролся с тем, что блоки добавлялись под уже размещенными.

**Пример моей реализации** ([песочница](https://jsfiddle.net/XmaSPb/x2ydzfuv/1/)):

```js
// external js: packery.pkgd.js

var $grid = $('.loadmore').packery({
  itemSelector: '.grid-promo'
});

$('.append-button').on( 'click', function() {
  // create new item elements
  var $items = getItemElement();
  // append elements to container
  $grid.append( $items )
    // add and lay out newly appended elements
    .packery( 'appended', $items );
});


// make <div class="grid-item grid-item--width# grid-item--height#" />
function getItemElement() {
  var $item = $('<div class="grid-promo grid-item--1x"><div class="div-1x">1x : 7</div></div><div class="grid-promo grid-item--2x"><div class="div-2x">2x : 8</div></div>');
  return $item;
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.loadmore {
}

/* clear fix */
.loadmore:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-promo {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
}

.grid-item--1x { width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.grid-item--2x { width: 50%; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.div-1x {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.div-2x {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff8800;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .grid-item--1x {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .grid-item--2x {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .div-2x {
    width: 562px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1199px) {
    .grid-item--1x {
        width: 33.333333%;
    }
    .grid-item--2x {
        width: 66.666666%;
    }
  .div-2x {
      width: 590px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .grid-item--1x {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .grid-item--2x {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .div-2x {
      width: 630px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .grid-item--1x {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .grid-item--2x {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .div-1x {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .div-2x {
      width: 100%;
    }
}


button { font-size: 20px; }
```

```html
<h1>Packery - appended</h1>

<div class="container">
  
<div class="row loadmore">
  <div class="grid-promo grid-item--1x">
    <div class="div-1x">
     1x : 1
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-promo grid-item--1x">
    <div class="div-1x">
     1x : 2
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-promo grid-item--2x">
    <div class="div-2x">
     1x : 3
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-promo grid-item--1x">
    <div class="div-1x">
     1x : 4
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-promo grid-item--1x">
    <div class="div-1x">
     1x : 5
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-promo grid-item--2x">
    <div class="div-2x">
     1x : 6
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
</div>

<p><button class="append-button">Append items</button></p>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2.1.2/dist/packery.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад, что у Вас получилось!